# How can I force two rotated matrices to have the same size irrespective of content?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, diagrams, matrices

I have two matrices which are rotated 45 degrees next to each other. Unfortunately, they are different sizes, likely because one has two-digit numbers, the other one digit.

How can I force them to be the same size?

[image]

Here is my MWE (thanks to @marmot for the original code):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{german}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes.geometric,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,transform canvas={rotate=45},
 nodes={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4,draw,rotate=-45,shape border             rotate=45},
 row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth]
 (mat)
 {03 & 13 & 23 & 33 \\ 
 02 & 12 & 22 & 32 \\ 
 01 & 11 & 21 & 31 \\ 
 00 & 10 & 20 & 30 \\ 
 };
 \path ([xshift=-3mm,yshift=3mm]mat.south west |- mat.north west) rectangle 
 ([xshift=3mm,yshift=-3mm]mat.south east -| mat.north east);
 \node at (mat.south west) {$\Phi_1$};
 \node at (mat.south east) {$\Phi_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,transform canvas={rotate=45},
 nodes={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4,draw,rotate=-45,shape border     rotate=45},
 row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth]
 (mat)
 {1 & 3 & 5 & 6 \\ 
 1 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
 1 & 2 & 3 & 3 \\ 
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
 };
 \path ([xshift=-3mm,yshift=3mm]mat.south west |- mat.north west) rectangle 
 ([xshift=3mm,yshift=-3mm]mat.south east -| mat.north east);
 \node at (mat.south west) {$\Phi_1$};
 \node at (mat.south east) {$\Phi_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Vereinigung zweier epistemischer Zustände $\Phi_1$ und $\Phi_2$     mittels Schlichtungsoperation $\Delta_{ls}$.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One only needs to add the `minimum size` key for both node styles in the two matrices:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{german}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes.geometric,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,transform canvas={rotate=45},
 nodes={minimum size=1.3cm,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4,draw,rotate=-45,shape border             rotate=45},
 row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth]
 (mat)
 {03 & 13 & 23 & 33 \\ 
 02 & 12 & 22 & 32 \\ 
 01 & 11 & 21 & 31 \\ 
 00 & 10 & 20 & 30 \\ 
 };
 \path ([xshift=-3mm,yshift=3mm]mat.south west |- mat.north west) rectangle 
 ([xshift=3mm,yshift=-3mm]mat.south east -| mat.north east);
 \node at (mat.south west) {$\Phi_1$};
 \node at (mat.south east) {$\Phi_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,transform canvas={rotate=45},
 nodes={minimum size=1.3cm,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4,draw,rotate=-45,shape border     rotate=45},
 row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth]
 (mat)
 {1 & 3 & 5 & 6 \\ 
 1 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
 1 & 2 & 3 & 3 \\ 
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
 };
 \path ([xshift=-3mm,yshift=3mm]mat.south west |- mat.north west) rectangle 
 ([xshift=3mm,yshift=-3mm]mat.south east -| mat.north east);
 \node at (mat.south west) {$\Phi_1$};
 \node at (mat.south east) {$\Phi_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another (nicer) solution thanks to [@marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot): We will add `text width={width(33)}` and `align=center` to the second matrix. Now the two matrices have the same size:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{german}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes.geometric,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,transform canvas={rotate=45},
 nodes={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4,draw,rotate=-45,shape border             rotate=45},
 row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth]
 (mat)
 {03 & 13 & 23 & 33 \\ 
 02 & 12 & 22 & 32 \\ 
 01 & 11 & 21 & 31 \\ 
 00 & 10 & 20 & 30 \\ 
 };
 \path ([xshift=-3mm,yshift=3mm]mat.south west |- mat.north west) rectangle 
 ([xshift=3mm,yshift=-3mm]mat.south east -| mat.north east);
 \node at (mat.south west) {$\Phi_1$};
 \node at (mat.south east) {$\Phi_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,transform canvas={rotate=45},
 nodes={text width={width(33)},regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4,draw,rotate=-45,shape border     rotate=45,align=center},
 row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth]
 (mat)
 {1 & 3 & 5 & 6 \\ 
 1 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
 1 & 2 & 3 & 3 \\ 
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
 };
 \path ([xshift=-3mm,yshift=3mm]mat.south west |- mat.north west) rectangle 
 ([xshift=3mm,yshift=-3mm]mat.south east -| mat.north east);
 \node at (mat.south west) {$\Phi_1$};
 \node at (mat.south east) {$\Phi_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @marmot Thank you very much! After adding `text width={width(33)}` I saw that the texts in the second matrix are not really centered, so I added an alignment option. Now the figure is much better indeed!

Comment: Thanks! Just out of curiosity - how did you come up with the width of 33? I am wondering how to apply the solution to other cases.

Comment: @Markus Well actually I'm not really familiar with Ti*k*Z's matrices. You should ask the original author marmot for this.